# Is it normal that Opencv's imread is giving me a 2-D Mat when I ask for a color image?

Tags: c++, image, opencv

So I have an .bmp image file in my folder.

I load it using imread:

```
  cv::Mat image = cv::imread( imageName, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR );
```

After that I look at the dimensions of it with:

```
std::cout<<"Rows: "<<image.rows <<"  Cols:"<<image.cols<<" Dims:"<<image.dims<<std::endl;
```

This gives me :

Rows: 480  Cols:640 Dims:2

But given that I had RGB image, shouldn't it also be 3D Mat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's normal.

`dims` is defined as (from the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)):

> **int dims;** //! the array dimensionality, >= 2

You should look at the [number of channels](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-channels) instead:

```
std:cout << "Channels: " << image.channels() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have another small question.  In fictions little zeros, there is a parameter ndim. I assume that isn't the same one as dim.

Comment: Yes it is. (Note that I pasted the wrong definition for _dims_. Now it's corrected)

Comment: Wait, so if I wanted to make an black rgb image ( do dim=2 and channels=3 how can I do that?

Comment: `Mat3b img(rows, cols, Vec3b(0,0,0))`, or `Mat img = Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_8UC3);`. You define the number of channels in the type of the matrix (**C3** stands for 3 channels). The `ndims` parameters is useful only for multidimensional matrix, but you don't need this for 2D matrices (e.g. images)

Comment: Last question. How do I use the 'at' functions with multiple layers? Do I do img.at<Vec3b>(x,y) and then get the rgb values?

Comment: Almost. `img.at<Vec3b>(row, col);` not (x,y), and the you get BGR values (not RGB)

Comment: How about when I use something like CV_32FC3?

Comment: Thank you a lot. I wont bother you anymore

Comment: So, what does the "dims" represent?

Comment: @mhaghighat it's the number of dimensions. For a regular 2D matrix is 2, for a 3D matrix is 3, and so on

Comment: So, does it mean that the RGB image is stored in a 2D matrix?!

Comment: @mhaghighat From OpenCV point of view: Yes. A 2D matrix where each element is a triplet BGR